# Import big txt file into matlab without cutting it

Tags: matlab, bigdata, mat

I have a text file whose size is  40000 x 40000, called for example "Name" the first line and first column are the labels and all other number are decimal numbers.
I need to save it into mat file in matlab without the labels, it means without the first line and first columns.

I have tried the following method:

```
data = importdata('Name.txt') ;  % 

save data.mat -v7.3
```

But, I get the data cut into only 590 x 590 , it means it's only a part of the data in the file.

How can I save the the whole data into mat file in matlab ?

**EDIT**

I also tried this way:

```
M = readmatrix('Name.txt');
M(:,1) = [];
```

It read all the rows number of 40000, but the columns are read till 587  !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you should find out where the error happens. Is your data read correctly?
The following solution should work in any case:

```
fID     = fopen('Name.txt');
headerline = fgetl(fID);
C       = textscan(fID,['%s' repmat('%f', 1, 40000)], 'Delimiter',  '\r');
dMat    = [C{2:end}];
save('Data.mat', 'dMat' , '-v7.3')
```

If this doesn't work you can always try to read the data via:

```
T = readtable('Name.txt')
```

and then have a look at the resulting table.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I get an error like this one:   Error using save
Must be a string scalar or character vector.

Comment: Regarding the read of data, it downloads only 587 x 578  out of the whole data

Comment: Yeah of course, sorry I corrected my answer for you

Comment: It saves empty data ! .. it means the saved file Data.mat is empty !

Comment: Yeah I accidently deleted the "fgetl" command, now it should work again...

Comment: Still empty file is saved.

Comment: The I need more information of the kind of data you are looking at. How does the dMat Variable look after reading the data? Does it contain all your data or is the error occuring before?

Comment: The data are all double number,  for example 2.66,  5.6 and so on. except the first row and first column they are string, for example ABC, ACD   ..etc .. But I need to remove the first first row and first column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231938/discussion-between-ben-s-and-gze).

Comment: okay, i think I finally gotit, are your values separated by commas? Then try this:' C       = textscan(fID,['%3s' repmat('%f,', 1, 40000)],1, 'Delimiter',  '\r');'

Comment: small note: you can use the `"headerlines",1` parameters directly in the call to `textscan` to tell it how many lines to ignore. That way you can get rid of the first `fgetl()` call.